# How to solve this 2-dimensional Poisson´s equation - PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We have 2 problems:

1)

$$U_{xx}(x,y)+U_{yy}(x,y)=f(x,y):=-\pi^2\sin{(\pi x)}\sin{(\pi y)}$$

The conditions are

$$1=U(0,y)=U(1,y)=U(x,0)=U(x,1)$$

2)

$$U_{xx}(x,y)+U_{yy}(x,y)-U(x,y)=f(x,y):=-\pi^2\sin{(\pi x)}\sin{(\pi y)}$$

The conditions are

$$1=U(0,y)=U(1,y)=U(x,0)=U(x,1)$$

Can someone give me the solutions?

I know, it is usual in this site that the students have tried the problems by themselves and talk where they have difficulties. I am not specially good at PDE because I have not studied it yet, but I need the solutions of 1) and 2) with urgency. I usually tried the problem by myself before asking (you can check my other questions)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Write $U=1+V$ and $V$ now has homogenous boundary conditions that are trivially solved in this case, because there is only one fourier component and it's the same as the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RHS of your two problems imply the solution.

We can guess the solution have the form $u=c \sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$ for these two problems which $c$ is a constant to be determined. Plug this solution into the PDEs and solve the $c$, we have $u=1/2\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$ for 1) and $u=\frac{\pi^2}{2\pi^2+1}\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$ for 2).

Comment: You said the solutions will have the form $$U=c \sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$$ for both cases.

So for 1) we have
$$U_{xx}+U_{yy}=-2c\pi^ 2\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$
it must equal to 

$$-\pi^2\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$. 

for finding $c$  you say $c=\frac{1}{2}$, because this give what we want, so $$U_{xx}+U_{yy}-\pi^2\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$. 

My question is  if $$f(x,y)=0$$
in other words, Laplace`s equations, what you said about the solutions will have this form is still valid?

$$c \sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$$?

Comment: Your understanding is right. For one thing, I do not see you say if $f=0$ in your original problem. For another, if $f=0$ there is another story and the solution can be imply by boundary condition (if it have closed form solution).

Comment: Thank you for responding the comment. Thank you for the solutions.
Now I am trying to figure out the solution for the case $f=0$, what I have is supposing the solution for 1) and $f=0$ will has the form $$U(x,y)=c\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1$$ 
then we have $U(x,y)$ satisfies the conditions but 
$$U_{xx}+U_{yy}=-2c\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\neq 0$$
the only case is for $c=0$
so the general solution without conditions 
$$c\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)+1=1$$ and $U(x,y)=1$ is the final solution ?

Is this the only solution for 1)?

Comment: In case 2), with $f=0$ and supposing the general solution is 
$$c\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) +1$$
then we will have this
$$U_{xx}+U_{yy}-U=(2\pi^2-1)c\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)-1=0$$

So how can we determinate $c$ to make it satisfying $U_{xx}+U_{yy}-U=f=0$ ?

Comment: I want to point out that there do not exist a general way to get the closed form solution for PDEs. Only a little kind of PDEs can be guessed by experience. In 1), if you want to find the solution in case $f=0$, you should pay eye to the boundary condition. Then you can easy to check $u=1$  is the solution. From the theoretical result, we know this is the unique solution. For 2), I can not guess what the solution is it.

Comment: BTW, if you are interest in what the solution it is, you can try series solution or numerical solution for it.

Comment: Thank you! I am taking PDE course next year !